# Recursive regex for div tags(not trying to parse html with regex)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a bunch of wiki markup, sometimes people just throw random html down in the middle of wiki markup and somehow wikipedia just rolls with it, as it does for all kinds of other badly formed wiki markup.  I want to match everything inside the divs.

I need to recursively find all the `<div>blah</div>` tags including div tags with other div tags inside them.  I am trying to match the div tags and everything inside of them.  I have this which I believe almost works:

```
new Regex(@"\<div.*?\> (?<DEPTH>)                   # opening 
            (?>                # now match...
               [^(\<div.*?\>)(\<\/div\>)]+          # any characters except divs
            |                  # or
               \<div.*?\>  (?<DEPTH>)  # a opening div, increasing the depth counter
            |                  # or
               \<\/div\>  (?<-DEPTH>) # a closing div, decreasing the depth counter
            )*                 # any number of times
            (?(DEPTH)(?!))     # until the depth counter is zero again
          \<\/div\>                   # then match the closing fix",
            RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Maybe I should be using another methodology to parse this but at this point this is the final regex statement that I need.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="infobox sisterproject" style="font-size: 90%; padding: .5em 1em 1em 1em;">
<div style="text-align:center;">
Find more about '''{{{display|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}''' on Wikipedia's [[Wikipedia:Wikimedia sister projects|sister projects]]:
</div><!--
-->{{#ifeq:{{{wikt}}}|no||<!--
-->[[File:Wiktionary-logo-en.svg|25px|link=wikt:Special:Search/{{{wikt|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Search Wiktionary]] [[wikt:Special:Search/{{{wikt|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Definitions]] from Wiktionary<br />}}<!--
-->{{#ifeq:{{{b}}}|no||<!--
-->[[File:Wikibooks-logo.svg|25px|link=b:Special:Search/{{{b|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Search Wikibooks]] [[b:Special:Search/{{{b|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Textbooks]] from Wikibooks<br />}}<!--
-->{{#ifeq:{{{q}}}|no||<!--
-->[[File:Wikiquote-logo.svg|25px|link=q:Special:Search/{{{q|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Search Wikiquote]] [[q:Special:Search/{{{q|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Quotations]] from Wikiquote<br />}}<!--
-->{{#ifeq:{{{s}}}|no||{{#ifeq:{{{author|no}}}|yes|<!--
-->[[File:Wikisource-logo.svg|25px|link=s:Special:Search/Author:{{{s|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Search Wikisource]] [[s:Special:Search/Author:{{{s|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Source texts]] from Wikisource<br />|<!--
-->[[File:Wikisource-logo.svg|25px|link=s:Special:Search/{{{s|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Search Wikisource]] [[s:Special:Search/{{{s|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Source texts]] from Wikisource<br />}}}}<!--
-->{{#ifeq:{{{commons}}}|no||<!--
-->[[File:Commons-logo.svg|25px|link=commons:Special:Search/{{{commons|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Search Commons]] [[commons:Special:Search/{{{commons|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Images and media]] from Commons<br />}}<!--
-->{{#ifeq:{{{n}}}|no||<!--
-->[[File:Wikinews-logo.svg|25px|link=n:Special:Search/{{{n|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Search Wikinews]] [[n:Special:Search/{{{n|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|News stories]] from Wikinews<br />}}<!--
-->{{#ifeq:{{{v}}}|no||<!--
-->[[File:Wikiversity-logo-Snorky.svg|25px|link=v:Special:Search/{{{v|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Search Wikiversity]] [[v:Special:Search/{{{v|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}}|Learning resources]] from Wikiversity<br />}}<!--
-->{{#ifeq:{{{species<includeonly>|no</includeonly>}}}|no||<!--
-->[[File:Wikispecies-logo.svg|25px|link=species:Special:Search/{{{species<noinclude>|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}</noinclude>}}}|Search Wikispecies]] [[species:Special:Search/{{{species<noinclude>|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}</noinclude>}}}|{{{species<noinclude>|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}</noinclude>}}}]] from Wikispecies}}
</div><noinclude>
```

Thanks

Comment: Admittedly without any knowledge of Wiki markup, wouldn't simply stripping all HTML tags be a better idea? Because as it stands, contrary to the question title you are indeed trying to parse HTML markup with a regex ;)

Comment: This might be defeatist but typically as soon as we have the words 'recursive' and 'regex' in the same sentence, 'impossible' isn't far behind; unless you manually run your own state machine to keep track of depths, calling multiple regexes yourself.  Regex's state machine can't handle this kind of thing I think.  It might help, however, if you say what you want matched out of that example.

Comment: "(not trying to parse html with regex)" <- hahaha, nice one! Obviously, you read some of the other questions with "html" and "regex". ;-)

Comment: "not trying to parse html with regex" ... Yes you are

Comment: No I'm not.  I'm trying to parse some crazy markup that uses some html tags but is not valid xml or valid html.  I have already recursively matched {} and [] so this must be possible.

Comment: I don't want to strip all html tags.  I want to match what is inside the div tags only.  This is not valid html or xml, I could not construct a dom out of this.

Comment: every time someone tries to parse html with regex, chuck norris kills a kitten.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not a good idea to parse the html with regex you could use the 
[Html Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: There are absolutely no other tags.  That is the only snippet with tags.  Would agility html pack accept that without me having to wrap fake html and head and body tags in the code?  And using invalid html characters?

Comment: It is allow you to parse html tags as Linq To Xml

Comment: yeah Html Agility wouldn't be necessary if you had perfectly formed XHTML, AND you used the .NET regex depth counters. Even then, I'd still use Agility, it's awesome and it deals with sloppy markup.

Answer (score 2):

```
 new Regex(@"<div\b[^>]*>(?><div\b[^>]*>(?<DEPTH>)|</div>(?<-DEPTH>)|.?)*(?(DEPTH)(?!))</div>", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

In the time it took me to fix my expression I would not even be half way done with getting html agility pack up and working.